# Template Does not Exist on IIS+Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, windows, django-templates, iis-8

After the deployment process of my Django website on IIS i am getting an error like below,

```
 TemplateDoesNotExist at /test/new_site/list/

Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: D:\workspace\One_Site_Project\env_one_site_37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\test\new_site_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: D:\workspace\One_Site_Project\env_one_site_37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\test\new_site_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: D:\workspace\One_Site_Project\env_one_site_37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\templates\test\new_site_list.html (Source does not exist)
```

I don't know why IIS is searching my templates files in virtualenv directory.

My view rendering code is,

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class NewSiteListUpdate(View):
    """
    This class is used to list all the new site activity, also update an activity
    """


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        List all the activity info or a particular activity info
        :param request:
        :param args:
        :param kwargs:
        :return:
        """
        if request.user.is_staff:
            self.data = ActivityInformation.objects.all()
            self.radius = 11111

        return render(request, 'test/new_site_list.html', {'data': self.data})
```

Below is my template settings in settings.py file,

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + '/template/'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            # 'builtins': [
            #     'src.huawei.templatetags.custom_tags'
            # ],
            'libraries':{
                'custom_tags': 'templatetags.custom_tags',
            },
        },
    },
]
```

Below is my project structure,

[image]

This is working fine in my local system. I tried to add the template folder in to the virtual directory also, but no use, still the same error is showing. I followed [this](https://www.mattwoodward.com/2016/07/23/running-a-django-application-on-windows-server-2012-with-iis/) tutorial in order to set up my application on IIS.

I am using python 3.7 and IIS 8.5

I spend my two days for solving this issue but i did not find any solution related to this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please show your `TEMPLATES` setting.

Comment: *I don't know why IIS is searching my templates files in virtualenv directory* - By default, Django searches the templates directories of your `INSTALLED_APPS`. One use of this is to load templates for the Django admin.

Comment: Where is the missing template located in your project? Are you sure it's checked in? Are you sure it should be `[BASE_DIR + '/template/']` and not `[BASE_DIR + '/templates/']. Please show the view that is failing as well.

Comment: @Alasdair the same thing is working in my local system. And my template is located in template directory only, not in templates

Comment: You've already said that it works locally, so repeating that doesn't help. Please show the layout of your project, including the `template` directory, and show the view that is failing as I asked.

Comment: @Alasdair  see i have edited my question as per your comment

Comment: Your view uses `huawei/new_site_list.html`, but there is no `huawei` directory in `template`. Please show the actual code and errors, otherwise we can't tell whether something is a real mistake in your code or a mistake when you changed the variable names.

Comment: Kindly see the updated question

Comment: The settings in your updated question should work. The *full* traceback might show what the problem is. I would also try printing `BASE_DIR` and `settings.TEMPLATES[0]['DIRS']`, to make sure they point to the correct locations.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to modify some part in your code

**settings.py**

try to change   **'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + '/template/']**, to **'DIRS'=[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'template'), ]**

**views.py**
The path made by the render function will be : **../template/huawei/new_site_list.html** but in your project structure  your don't have a folder **huawei**. You must write : **return render(request, 'test/new_site_list.html', {'data': self.data})**